# Counting/combinatorics problem: How many people do not eat either tacos, salmon, or a burger?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on this counting/combinatorics problem. Can figure if it's a trick question or what kind of technique I should use. Please help.

There are these people who eat either Tacos, Salmon or Burger:

11 eats tacos

11 eats salmon

11 eats burger

3 eats taco and salmon

4 eats taco and burger

7 eat salmon and burger

1 eats taco, salmon and burger

If there are 25 people in a set, how many do **not** eat either tacos, salmon or burger?

Comment: Look up "inclusion-exclusion principle".

Comment: If you are not familiar with the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, draw a Venn diagram.  Start from the middle and work your way out.

Comment: So: |11| + |11| + |11| - |3| - |7| - |4| - |1| = 18 ?

Comment: @AmyA usually not; the "3 eat taco and salmon" would normally include the one also eating burgers. Really recommend the Venn diagram, maybe alongside an inclusion-exclusion calculation.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. Im confused as to how the 25 people fit in in a Venn diagram (and the problem in general)?

Comment: @AmyA Do you recognize $A \cap B$ and $A \cap B \cap C$ in Venn diagram? Then you can fill appropriate numbers in them.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Whenever filling numbers in a Venn diagram, you first write $A \cap B \cap C$. Then subtract that from $A \cap B, A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ and write those. Then subtract them from $A, B $ and $C$  and write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Inclusion-Exclusion principle, the number of people who eat atleast one of the items is

$$|T|+|S|+|B|-|T \cap S|-|S \cap B|-|T \cap B|+|T \cap S \cap B|$$
$$=11+11+11-3-7-4\color{red}{+1}=20$$

To get the number of people who do not eat any, subtract this number from total number of people. $25-20=5$.

Answer (score 2):

We can solve the problem using a Venn diagram.

Let $B$ be the set of people who eat a burger, $S$ be the set of people who eat salmon, and $T$ be the set of people who eat a taco.

Start from the inside:  Since $|B \cap S \cap T| = 1$, we place a $1$ in $B \cap S \cap T$.

We are given that
\begin{align*}
|B \cap S| & = 7\\
|B \cap T| & = 4\\
|S \cap T| & = 3
\end{align*}
Since we have already accounted for the one person who eats all three dishes, we place a $6$ in $B \cap S$ outside $B \cap S \cap T$ since $B \cap S \cap T' = 6$.  Similarly, we place a $3$ in $B \cap T$ outside $B \cap S \cap T$ and a $2$ in $S \cap T$ outside $B \cap S \cap T$.

If we now look at set $B$, we see that we have accounted for $10$ of the $11$ people who eat a burger since $|B \cap S \cap T'| + |B \cap S' \cap T| + |B \cap S \cap T| = 6 + 3 + 1 = 10$.  Therefore, we must place a $1$ in $B \cap S' \cap T'$.

Since we have already placed $9$ of the $11$ people in set $S$, we must place a $2$ in $B' \cap S \cap T'$.  Since we have already placed $6$ of the $11$ people in set $T$, we must place a $5$ in $B' \cap S' \cap T$.

If we now add all the people we have placed in sets $B$, $S$, and $T$, we conclude that $1 + 6 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 5 = 20$ eat a burger, salmon, or a taco.  Since there are a total of $25$ people, $25 - 20 = 5$ eat none of those items.

[image: Venn_diagram]

If we simply add the people who eat a burger, the people who eat salmon, and the people who eat a taco, we will have counted each person who eats two of those dishes  twice, once for each dish they ate. However, we only want to count them once, so we must subtract them from the total.
$$|B| + |S| + |T| - |B \cap S| - |B \cap T| - |S \cap T|$$
However, doing so subtracts too much.  We counted the person who eats all three meals three times when we added the number of people who eat a burger, eat salmon, or eat a taco, once for each dish that person ate, then subtracted them three times, once for each of the three pairs of dishes they ate.  Thus, we have not counted that person at all.  Thus, we must add that person to the total.  Thus, the number of people who eat at least one of the dishes is
\begin{align*}
|B \cup S \cup T| & = |B| + |S| + |T| - |B \cap S| - |B \cap T| - |S \cap T| + |B \cap S \cap T|\\
& = 11 + 11 + 11 - 7 - 4 - 3 + 1\\
& = 20
\end{align*}
so the number of people who eat none of the dishes is
$$|U| - |B \cup S \cup T| = 25 - 20 = 5$$